# Sending an email from a node server using gmail credentials

Tags: node.js, rest, server, gmail

I want to be able to send emails from my node server. I've created a `google developer project` and enabled the `gmail api` in it. After that I downloaded the credentials for `gmail api` in json format. But I cannot lookup the `nodemailer` documentation since the site appears to be down.

How do I send emails from my node server using the gmail credentials I downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to send mail using nodemailer.create the express app using below code.

```
 var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: 'test@gmail.com', //Gamilid that was created by you
      pass: 'password'
    },
    secure: true
  });


  // app.get('/send',function(req,res){
  var mailOptions = {
    to: 'sampleto@testcom',
    subject: "MAIL TEST",
    text: "Hi this is the test mail"
  }
  console.log(mailOptions);


  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.end("error");
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
      res.end("sent");
    }
  });
```

Comment: is nodemailer an npm?